# Array com variaves via POST

Tags: php, mysql

Meu html esta assim:

```
<input name='nDup[]' type='text'>
<input name='dVenc[]' type='text'>
<input name='vDup[]' type='text'>
```

Recebendo esses dados via POST (Que são os inputs acima, podem ser repetidos uma ou mais vezes dependendo o numero de duplicatas que tiver)

```
$nDup = $_POST['nDup'];
$dVenc = $_POST['nDup'];
$vDup = $_POST['nDup'];
```

Preciso montar um `array` igual a esse, com esses valores do POST:

```
$aDup = array(
    array('carlos','2016-06-20','300.00'),
    array('mario','2016-07-20','300.00'),
    array('joao','2016-08-20','300.00'),
    array('silvio','2016-09-20','300.00')
);
```

Pois preciso preencher um foreach abaixo com esses valores

```
foreach ($aDup as $dup) {
    $nDup = $dup[0];
    $dVenc = $dup[1];
    $vDup = $dup[2];
    $resp = $nfe->tagdup($nDup, $dVenc, $vDup);
}
```

---

Fiz assim, será que está certo?

```
$nDup = $_POST['nDup'];
$dVenc = $_POST['nDup'];
$vDup = $_POST['nDup'];

$matrizDuplicata = array($nDup,$dVenc,$vDup);

foreach ($matrizDuplicata as $dup)
{
    $nDup = $dup[0];
    $dVenc = $dup[1];
    $vDup = $dup[2];
    $resp = $nfe->tagdup($nDup, $dVenc, $vDup);
}
```

Comment: Pelo o que descreveu na pergunta, o problema é exatamente o mesmo e a função `array_map` irá resolver, basta passar como `null` o primeiro parâmetro e os *arrays* nos outros parâmetros, assim como foi respondido. Se não é esse o problema, recomendo que edite a pergunta e tente deixá-la mais clara.

Comment: Farei o teste..obrigado..